# Email Summary report after jmeter load test

Tags: maven, email, jmeter

I want to be able to email the summary report after the jmeter load test to 'abc@gmail.com'.

I'm running the jmeter load test from maven.

Any leads on this would be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Did you bother to do a search?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33632028/jmeter-result-report-emailing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JMeter: Result/Report Emailing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33632028/jmeter-result-report-emailing)

Comment: @OldProgrammer I looked at that. But i didn't see anywhere where i could attach the index.html and send the email.

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all you need to generate a summary report. I would recommend going for [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) in conjunction with [Maven Exec plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/), the command line would be something like:

   ```
   JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv report.csv --input-jtl result.jtl --plugin-type SynthesisReport
   ```

   You can install JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) for ad-hoc usage or add it via [JMeter Maven plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-additional-libraries-to-the-classpath#adding-jars-to-the-libext-directory) like:

   ```
   <configuration>
       <jmeterExtensions>
           <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-cmd:2.1</artifact>
       </jmeterExtensions>
   </configuration>
   ```
2. Once done you should be able to send the generated `report.csv` using [Maven Postaman Plugin](http://doc.fortysix.ch/maven/maven-postman-plugin/index.html)

Comment: Once the test is run, the reports are saved in the target folder. I want to be able to email the index.html file.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the maven-postman plugin to send an email.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>ch.fortysix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-postman-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>send a mail</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>send-mail</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <from>abc@abc.in</from>
                        <subject>Load test Results</subject>
                        <failonerror>true</failonerror>
                        <mailhost>mail.abc.com</mailhost>
                        <receivers>
                            <receiver>abc@abc.in</receiver>
                        </receivers>
                        <fileSets>
                            <fileSet>
                                <directory>${basedir}/target/jmeter/results</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>*.csv</include>
                                </includes>
                            </fileSet>
                        </fileSets>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This worked for me.